# How to look through post in Reddit with praw

Tags: reddit, python-3.5, praw

I've been looking at the documentation for praw and i simply cannot find which method is for looking through all the post.
What I want to do is look through all the post

```
import ProcessingBot
import Auth
import praw

SETPHRASES = ["python", "bots", "jarmahent", "is proves there was no Global     Warming in 1966", "test"]
SETPHRASE = ("This is a bot, ignore this reply")
USERNAME = Auth.pG

def run():
    r = praw.Reddit(Auth.app_ua)
    print("Signing In")

    r.set_oauth_app_info(Auth.app_id, Auth.app_secret, Auth.app_uri)
    print("Setting Oauth App Info")

    r.refresh_access_information(Auth.app_refresh)

    sub = r.get_subreddit("ProcessingImages")
    print("Getting SubReddit")
    for: #Look through all the post this is where the post finder will be

    print("Finished")




return r


while True:
    run()
```

The formatting is a little wrong, I spaced 4 times and pasted and it still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the example on [the documentation front page](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/):

```
>>> import praw
>>> r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='my_cool_application')
>>> submissions = r.get_subreddit('opensource').get_hot(limit=5)
>>> [str(x) for x in submissions]
```

Aside from [`get_hot`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_hot), there are also methods for [rising](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_rising) and [top](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_top) posts.