# How to retrieve a reddit post by id using praw?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914185/how-to-look-through-post-in-reddit-with-praw) that we can use [praw package](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html) to read posts from Reddit. I checked the API documentation and only know how to retrieve the post either by [top](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/subreddit.html?highlight=top#praw.models.Subreddit.top) or [hot](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/subreddit.html?highlight=top#praw.models.Subreddit.hot). My question is there any API endpoint for me to get the post by its ID?

Take the below post for example:
https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/kyg9nc/if_your_smart_lock_is_not_unlocking_or_you_want/

I believe the ID of this post is **kyg9nc**. Is there a suggested way to retrieve this post by its ID or any way to retrieve a specific post? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The id of your post would be kyg8nc. A way to retrieve the post with praw would be like this:

```
# reddit being your logged in instance with praw
reddit.submission(id='kyg8nc')
```